# Create Custom fields on Document object

Tags: custom-field, document

Is it possible to create Custom Fields on Document object. If not is there documentation which says that custom fields cannot be created on Document Object.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any specific `SF Docs` can directly say, *Document object doesn't accept custom field creation.*

But Please refer this [docx](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custom_field_allocations.htm&type=5) which describes the Salesforce objects which are have Custom field creation option and I can't find *Document* object here.

So I hope it's will give some idea to you.

Thanks.